# VSTS - Post test results from a build to an API end point

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to post test results (e.g number of tests passed/failed) to a reporting api. I was thinking to publish the results in xml and add a powershell step to read and extract the information from the xml file and make a post request to the api.

[image]

Has anyone tried this way or is there a better way of achieving the same thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to host an additional service you could publish your test results as a build artifact and access it via the VSTS API, then parse it and then post it to your destination API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/artifacts/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=4.1
```

---

If you decide to parse the test results in the build task with powershell you can use build tasks to make the API call to your destination API endpoint.

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CdiscountAlm.rest-call-build-task

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not sure if you can pass your test results as body in 'Rest Call' task. I will add my implementation as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.

[image]

I didn't need task 'Publish Test Results' since 'Test Assemblies' task is doing it already.

Test results are being published as .trx file since I am using xUnit as a test framework.

My powershell script looks something like this.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\<ProjectFolder>\Scripts\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")

$resultFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path ".\TestResults\*.trx"      

foreach ($resultFile in $resultFiles) {
    Write-Output $resultFile

    $data = [xml](Get-Content $resultFile)    
    $json = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode($data)
    $json = $json -replace '"@', '"'

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://my-azure-function/api/VstsWebhook?buildId=$Env:BUILD_BUILDID&buildNumber=$Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER&code=<secret>" -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $json
}
```

Hope this will help others in the same situation.